# Will WCF automatically encode my XML conent?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

E.g. the WCF Service creates an XDocument with an element like this:

```
string content = &lt;Wibble&gt";
XDocument message = new XDocument( new XELement("ElName", content) );
```

Our clients are stating that they get the above back as:

```
<ElName><Wibble></ElName>
```

We've not found any decode code in our WCF service or their client code.  I think we're missing something, though could it be that WCF or XDocument is turning `&lt;Wibble&gt` into `<Wibble>` ?  Note that we're using Net TCP binary encoding.

Thanks

Comment: What happens when *you* test it against your service?

Comment: I'm only getting round to testing it now (it's been one of those particulary manic days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening when we called InnerText rather than InnerXml on an XmlDocument element.  It seems that calling InnerText returns decoded XML.